# Galois group of $x^4-2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I need to determine the Galois group of $f(x) = x^4-2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$. I have shown that $f(x)$ is irreducible over the field. I think there are two ways to go forward:

1. Build the field $F = \mathbb{Z}_{7}/\langle x^4-2\rangle$. Then, look at the degree of $F/\mathbb{Z}_{7}$. This is the way I'm most interested in, and I'd appreciate some thorough help with this idea.
2. Find an arbitrary root $\alpha$ and proceed. This is the way my professor prescribed. I could also benefit with advice here, as I'm not sure what he meant.

Thank you for your considerate help!

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial is reducible, since $2^4 \equiv 5^4 \equiv 2 \mod 7.$

Comment: How do I proceed with the cubic then?

Comment: @Moz It's not a cubic, it's a quadric (since 2 and 5 are both roots).